# Verizon Email Sign-In Failed

Tags: email, password, verizon

This error message is for a Verizon email account on a Samsung Galaxy S5 phone. This afternoon it started saying the password changed and wanted me to put the new password in, but I did NOT change my password. So I have no clue. This isn't the first time this has happened. I don't remember what fixed it the other times.

Is it a Verizon issue or my account or my phone? So frustrating to keep hearing the notification over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call Verizon? If not, it might help. Also, try clicking forgot password.